# Limiting the options in an Opportunity to a linked Account?

Tags: sales

We have sales reps approaching different school sports teams. Rather than making a different Account for each team, we have one account for the school and a list of sports that are present at that school. When creating an opportunity, the reps pick which team(s) are involved. We're using a text search box that contains all sports. The reps complain that this is tough to use, since there are so many sports. Is there a way to limit the options to only sports that are offered by the linked school?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to create a Sport (`Sport__c`) object with a Lookup Field to `Account`, and create each of the Sport objects as children from the `Account` record. Next, we can create a lookup field to the Sport object on the Opportunity, and add a [Lookup Filter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_lookup_filters.htm&type=5) to limit the options to the Account (Sport.Account__c equals Opportunity.AccountId). This would allow the search/typing feature as well as limiting the options to the selected school.

Comment: Thank you, this is massively helpful!